# Updated Xubuntu, Postgres Stopped Working

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I updated my Xubunutu, It was originally 19.04 when I install on this labtop, I think I did one update in the past, now on Xubuntu 19.10.

Postgres was working just prior to the upgrade, I think I may have two versions of postgres running but many of the solutions I've seen don't seem to work.

When I type: service postgresql status

I get

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-12-09 07:33:43 EST; 4h 30min ago
 Main PID: 1217 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Dec 09 07:33:43 alexmerced-X550EA systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dec 09 07:33:43 alexmerced-X550EA systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

when I type: dpkg -l | grep postgres

I get:

```
ii  postgresql                            11+204ubuntu0.1                        all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-11                         11.5-1                                 amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 11 server
ii  postgresql-client-11                  11.5-1                                 amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-common              204ubuntu0.1                           all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                     204ubuntu0.1                           all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

When I type: pg_lsclusters

I get:

```
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

Just in case: psql -h /tmp

```
psql -h /tmp
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

```
sudo service postgres restart
Failed to restart postgres.service: Unit postgres.service not found.
```

```
ps aux |grep postgres
alexmer+ 26272  0.0  0.0   9028   916 pts/2    S+   12:11   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix came in by uninstall all the packages from the dpkg results in the OP, then reinstalling with sudo apt-get install postgresql.

now reconfiguring my users